# magento Call to a member function setOrder() on a non-object

Tags: magento

I am following [this](http://www.about-magento.com/magento-model-database-tutorial-54) tutorial, trying to learn to make Magento extensions, however, in step 4, I get the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function setOrder() on a non-object in  C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Pfay\Test\Block\Monblock.php on line 7**

Am I doing something wrong? I am working on Magento 1.6.1

Hosh

PS: On a side note, anyone know a good tutorial on creation extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your resource collection isn't found.  That tutorial has incorrect xpath for the models declaration - it's inside the `<global />` node, not under the root `<config />` node. The tutorial and its explanation are not very good. An excellent place to start is Alan Storm's Magento for Developers articles in the Magento Knowledgebase. Start here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Comment: Cheers for the link, I wonder why Google didn't show me that link :/
Also, I know that, it didn't want to show anything, so I had a look at one of the core config.xml files, and found out it was supposed to be in the <config /> tag. Any other suggestions?